# jupyter notebookでプログラム作成中、ファイルのパス設定が分からない

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

下記のショットのように、jupyterでプログラムにファイル読み込みを書き入れて実行するとエラーが出ます。ファイルを何処に置いたらよいのか　又は　ファイルへのパス設定はどのようにするのか教えてください。プログラムは初心者です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

jupyter notebookに限った話ではないですが以下コマンドでカレントディレクトリが表示されますので、そこにファイルを格納していただければよいと思います。

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

jupyter notebookの場合'C:\Users\「ユーザー名」がデフォルトかと思います。

下記コマンドで変更も可能です。

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=<directory>
```