# tensor flow をjupyter notebookで使っているんですがtensor boardが使えません。

Tags: python, tensorflow

初心者です。
tensor flow をjupyter notebookで使っているんですがtensor boardが使えません。
下記のプログラムをjupyter notebook上で打ち込んでtensorboad --logdir=/path/to/log
をターミナルで打ち込みましたがうまくいきません。
教えてもらえると有難いです。

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
LOG_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname("__file__"), 'log')
if os.path.exists(LOG_DIR) is False:
    os.mkdir(LOG_DIR)
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
y = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, w)+b)

cross_entropy = - tf.reduce_sum(t*tf.log(y)+(1-t)*tf.log(1-y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.to_float(tf.greater(y, 0.5)), t)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
tf.train.SummaryWriter(LOG_DIR, sess.graph)
sess.run(init)
```

Comment: tensorboardコマンド時のエラー内容も貼り付けて頂けるとみなさん回答しやすいかと思います。また、念のためですがtensorboad --logdir=/path/to/logの/path/to/logはあなたの環境のディレクトリを指定する必要があります。

Comment: ブラウザでhttp://localhost:6006/を開いてみました。
下記のように出ました。

No scalar data was found.

Probable causes:

You haven't written any scalar data to your event files.
TensorBoard can't find your event files.
If you're new to using TensorBoard, and want to find out how to add data and set up your event files, check out the README and perhaps the TensorBoard tutorial .

If you think TensorBoard is configured properly, please see the section of the README devoted to missing data problems and consider filing an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

マルチポスト先の記事を拝見致しました。
https://teratail.com/questions/80320

```
t‌​ensorboad --logdir=/path/to/log
```

/path/to/logはそのまま打つのではなくあなたの環境のログ保存位置を指定する必要があります。
つまり
`os.path.dirname("__file__")`ですのでscript実行位置の下のlogフォルダです。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。/path/to/logはそのまま打つのではなく環境のログ保存位置を指定する必要があることわかりました。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　script実行位置とは何になるんでしょうか？　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　プログラムを勉強し始めたばかりで恥ずかしくもわかりません。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。/path/to/logはそのまま打つのではなく環境のログ保存位置を指定する必要があることわかりました。　　　　　　　script実行位置とは何になるんでしょうか？プログラムを勉強し始めたばかりで恥ずかしくも分かりません。また、今回のような＄から始まることがわかるには何を勉強すればいいですか？　返信頂けると助かります。

Comment: あなたのtensorflowスクリプトの実行位置(の下のlogフォルダ)です。参考：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/35405

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。助かりました